What's the term for "attributing to a subgroup what's true of the whole"?
I'm searching for a term or word that might not exist. Here's what I'm trying to label:

The tendency of us humans to attribute to a subgroup what's true of the whole. Or the act of doing so.

Examples:

"We (insert nation) are really bad at (insert thing)." -- when it's clear that people, in general, are bad at it, and there's no reason to believe the speaker's nation is any worse than others.
"This (bad thing) can only happen here in (nation/industry/group)." -- when it's, in fact, happening everywhere.
"See? These (group) people are simply not that interested in (virtuous thing)." -- when there's no reason to believe they are any less interested in it than people in general.

I went through different lists of fallacies and biases, and I asked on social media, but so far, I don't think I have the answer.
It's definitely a form of generalization/stereotype, but it stops at a subgroup even though the exact same generalization/stereotype could be just as well applied to a larger group.
Is there a term for this? If not, what would you suggest as the best, succinct way to describe this?

Fallacy of division.

It's kind of like a distinction without a difference

I was going to say, 'normal'. You're trying to have a name for some people doing what everyone does.

When attributing negative characteristics to an outgroup, it would be "outgroup bias." There's no corresponding name that I know of for attributing negative characteristics to an ingroup. If inventing a name for it, you might call it "group exceptionalism." (e.g. ingroup exceptionalism)

Ah, thank you @causative! 'Exceptionalism' brought me on the right track, I think. Here's a citation from political scientist Noritada Matsuda: "[W]hat is seemingly exceptional in one country may be found in other countries." This is a great example of what I'm talking about.

What is? (Has Matsuda mentioned attributing anything to anyone?)

@Bumble is correct. As a statistician the first thing that came to my mind was ecological fallacy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy). I think that is sort of the quantitative/statistical counterpart of the fallacy of division.

@filiph It seems like you're talking about the reverse of "hasty generalization". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization#Hasty_generalization In your examples it seems like people making those statements would already have an existing opinion and the statements they make are confirming their own opinions.  That makes a case of confirmation bias in addition to whatever else it is.

My research indicates that there is no term for this kind of fallacy.
I have consulted four of my ChatGPT personas:

Thomas Aquinas Emulator
Thomas Epistemes
Sir Lafferlot
Doctor Laffologue

I have collected all of their suggestions:

localization fallacy
subgroup fallacy
subgroup attribution fallacy
subgroup universality fallacy
subgroup myopia
subgroup essentialization
subgroup exceptionalism
micro-generalization
subspecific bias

But perhaps it should be called exceptionalism fallacy.

For what it's worth, me 2 cents follow:
The fallacy is a variant of sweeping/hasty generalization in which we start off with a bad sample (biased/too small) and draw erroneous conclusions about the population. After that the erring person might think it justified to infer of some subgroup what is true of the parent group (the population). Basically inferring something further from hasty/sweeping generaization.
For example: If I meet only 2 Greeks and both like sushi, I conclude that all Greeks like sushi (the first mistake, a hasty generalization). Further down the road, so to speak, I meet Christian Greeks and then conclude Christian Greeks like sushi (the second mistake).
Moreover, some subgroups maybe in the minority and won't show up in a statistical study. There are ways to remedy that (e.g. stratified/cluster sampling, but that's a topic for another day). In such cases, your findings (based on the majority) can't be extended to the minority. This is not a case of hasty generalization, the minority is simply overwhelmed by the majority. It's also not a fallacy if you make explicit the degree of confidence you have in your inference.

What is the term for "attributing to the subgroup what is true of the whole"?
Well, the term for this question is, "you learn something new every day," because that’s what happened to me.
It turns out that the question describes the fallacy of division and composition, which I had never heard of before. More specifically, the question asks about the fallacy of division.

The fallacy of composition and division makes the assumption that one
part of something will apply to the whole, or that the whole must
apply to all the parts.
Example of Fallacy of Composition and Division


Composition: Each part of this chair is cheap, so the whole chair for sale must be cheap.


Division: Healthy brains think. Healthy brains are comprised of nothing but brain cells. If healthy brains think, then the individual brain cells can think too.

Source: logicalfallacies.org (emphasis mine).
Also, if the argument involved people, this might involve the ad hominem fallacy.
Thanks for this interesting question!

This is not it. How would you apply this to any of the examples given? e.g. ' "This (bad thing) can only happen here in (nation/industry/group)." -- when it's, in fact, happening everywhere. ' In that example, what is the whole, and what are the parts that compose it, and what is the fallaciously shared attribute? If anything, it's the opposite of division/composition: it's assuming without evidence that one part is different from the others.

@causitive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition If you attribute a property to the entire earth that only applies to a region of the earth, you are committing fallacy of composition. Example: Conflict diamonds in Africa show that procuring diamonds is unethical in practice. Counterexample: 1st world nations, in fact, can manufacture diamonds with machines ethically.

@JD But that's the opposite of the question scenario. In the question, there is a property that only applies to a region of the earth, and you assume the rest of the earth does not have this property.

@causative.  I answered the question as asked in the caption. I did not addresss the examples in the supporting text

@causative You're right about the logical distinction, but the fallacy isn't as granular. Essentially, any inference that imputes properties of either the part or whole to the whole or part respectively qualifies. The fallacy is simply that one cannot reason about the other with any reliability because parts of wholes are different than wholes. So, the logical distinctions might be good to subsect claims, but they don't make a difference for applying the fallacy as a category.
